# Application of differentiation (Volume)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A right circular cone of height,h, is inscribed in a sphere of radius R.  Show that the volume V of the cone is given by $V=\frac{\pi}{2}(2Rh^2-h^3)$.

My answer that I found is $V=\frac{\pi}{3}(2Rh^2-h^3)$ instead of $V=\frac{\pi}{2}(2Rh^2-h^3)$. Is the question wrong?

My attempt,

$$h=R+x$$, where R is radius of sphere and h is height of cone
$$r^2=R^2-x^2$$
$$r=\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$$

$$V=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2(h)$$

$$=\frac{1}{3}\pi (h)(R-x)(h)$$

$$=\frac{1}{3}\pi (Rh^2-xh^2)$$

$$=\frac{1}{3}\pi (Rh^2-(h-R)h^2)$$

$$=\frac{1}{3}\pi (2Rh^2-h^3)$$

Comment: Could you show some of your work?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yea sure, I'm editing the post.

Comment: I just did a quick calculation and it agrees with your answer.  So, either we both did the same mistake or the "answer" is wrong.

Comment: I just edited the post @michael Burr

Comment: As a check, try the case where $h=R$, in this case, the base of the cone passes through the center of the sphere and the radius of the base is $R$.  This makes an easy calculation for the volume of the cone, which you can use to check your answer easily.

Comment: I also agree with your answer. FWIW, I used slightly different geometry to what you did in the question (similar triangles in a right triangle on a diameter). So it looks like the question is wrong. I'm suspicious of any cone volume formula that doesn't have a ⅓ in it. :) BTW, the tags on your question are misleading. This is a geometry question, not a calculus question, per se.

Comment: Your answer is correct.